# Have basic autoindentation in code blocks in org-mode

Tags: emacs, indentation, org-mode

Emacs' fine org-mode has CODE and EXAMPLE blocks that are easily edited in a proper major mode using `C-c '`. But for quick alterations and minor edits one might prefer editing the block inline without opening new popup windows for a two-second operations.

Of course org lets you do that but the automatic indentations are off radar while editing inline like that. Where and what should I hack to make org's indentation logic to act like default dumb autoindentation (ie. copy the indent level of the previous line) *while* the cursor is in a code block?

```
  #+BEGIN_SRC python
    def foo():
        return 42
  #+END_SRC

  #+BEGIN_EXAMPLE
    Oh my
         hh
  #+END_EXAMPLE
```

If the cursor was at the end of the line containing `hh`, pressing `C-j` would get me a new line with the same indentation as the previous one.

Answer (score 3):

The following allows me to edit (and indent) code "inline" without ever going to the indirect buffers (except for M-q on comments, which did work and does not anymore).

```
;; same effect for `tab' as in the language major mode buffer
(setq org-src-tab-acts-natively t)
```

Comment: That sounds better than hoped but I didn't get it working just yet. I'll come back when I do.

Comment: late for the party but is there any progress on this? Can't believe i'm having the same issue after 6 years!